# Intellij IDE is blocking my app from running

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

Im trying to create an ATM-ish project and I wired some reading-writing to a txt file. I tried to test out what I've written so far but Intellij is blocking my application from running. It's the only project that it blocks the run and the other buttons . What can I do about it? Is it something about the code? I've also tried closing and re-opening the IDE but nothing. Thanks!  Thanks ! ( Code: 1st class: http://pastebin.com/wnPxBQUN  , 2nd class: http://pastebin.com/pijwqRJg ) .

[image: Printscreen of my intellij idea]

Comment: If you want to run desktop app (does not matter if console or window) click RMB on class where you have main method and just run. Or add configuration you can find how to do it 

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html?origin=old_help

Comment: Thanks a ton Peter! It worked :) .